# Apereo CAS two-factor authentication with REST

Tags: authentication, cas, apereo

I have enabled two-factor authentication in Apereo CAS 6.5 and it works well using CAS UI page available on /login endpoint. I use CAS simple provider.

If I provide username and password then I am asked about providing two-factor code. After that I insert the code and I am logged in.

I wonder if it is possible to enable two-factor for CAS REST protocol? I would like to be asked for two-factor code while generating TGT via REST.

I enabled global trigger for multi factor authentication and I am unable to get two-factor code as I am getting through login page.

Answer (score 0):

> I wonder if it is possible to enable two-factor for CAS REST protocol? I would like to be asked for two-factor code while generating TGT via REST.

If you mean whether this capability is available out of the box, the answer is no. Of course, you could always modify and extend the software to build this use case yourself.

Comment: To implement such feature I need to implement class that will send 2fa token like CasSimpleMultifactorSendTokenAction does, am I right? Or can I use this class somehow?